# awk print 1st row with condition

Tags: bash, awk

The command:

```
kubectl get pods -n hello | awk '$1 ~ "hello-uwsgi-deployment"  {print $1}'
```

outputs

```
hello-uwsgi-deployment-5b7498f864-4bfrx
hello-uwsgi-deployment-5b7498f864-h9rxz
hello-uwsgi-deployment-5b7498f864-qlg8z
hello-uwsgi-deployment-5b7498f864-r5nfs
hello-uwsgi-deployment-5b7498f864-vxr6x
```

How can I print only the first line with the above condition using `awk`?

I tried

```
kubectl get pods -n hello |
awk '($1 ~ "hello-uwsgi-deployment") && ('NR==1') {print $1}'
```

but it outputs nothing.

EDIT:`kubectl get pods -n hello | awk '($1 ~ /hello-uwsgi-deployment/){print;exit}'` this works perfectly.

How to get the same working with multiple conditional statements using `==` and `NR==`?

Comment: You can use the exit statement. The `exit` statement will finish processing any input and directly go to the `END` section of awk. If there is no END, it will terminate awk. So just do `(condition) { print $1; exit }`

Comment: You didn't add single quotes around your first condition (`$1 ~ "hello-uwsgi-deployment"`) if you just had done the same for your second condition (i.e. wrote `NR==1` instead of `'NR==1'`) then your script would have worked, just a bit less efficiently than adding `exit` to the acrion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to print only first line which has string `hello-uwsgi-deployment` then could you please try following. I am also using `exit` so that it will NOT read whole Input_file and will save time for us.

```
kubectl get pods -n hello | awk '($1 ~ /hello-uwsgi-deployment/){print;exit}'
```

---

---

OR of you want to simply do search string in whole line then try following:

```
kubectl get pods -n hello | awk '/hello-uwsgi-deployment/{print;exit}'
```

Comment: The key point is to `exit` after the (first) print.  I'm not sure the parentheses are necessary; the code in the question didn't need them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Thank you :) yes you are right they are not necessary I added them for better understanding we could remove it too,cheers :)

Comment: this command works perfectly for this use case, but question is how to get awk working with multiple conditions for the same use case

Comment: @MR.i, This code was given for shown question and sample. In case you have any other requirement/question then please do add them in your question itself and let me know as your question `but question is how to get awk working with multiple conditions for the same use case`.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output to head command:

```
kubectl get pods -n hello | awk '$1 ~ "hello-uwsgi-deployment"  {print $1}' | head -n 1
```

Comment: That is works fine and I have tried it, how do I get the same output with just awk?